# Forecast of a time series with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, prometheus, arima

I apologize in advance if I will say nonsense, I have zero experience in this field. Unfortunately my teacher had the brilliant idea to explain time series forecasting in only 3 hours (and I'm a computer engineering student, not a data science student, so for me it is a totally new topic!) and I didn't understand much about it.

Context: in my project I generate a metric in Spring Boot with Micrometer (a counter, that counts the number of purchases), I use Prometheus to pull this metric and I generate a .csv file with Grafana. Then I open this file with Python e I create the time series using Panda's dataframe.

This is my time series:
[time_series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fZc.png)

My teacher explained that the first thing to do is to apply the seasonal_decompose filter and extract the trend of the series:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(ts, model='...', period=...)
trend = result.trend
```

And here my first questions: in model do I have to insert "additive" or "multiplicative"? And then, what period do I have to insert? My series is aperiodic! In class it has been explained to us only the case of a "beautiful" series with particular features, but my series is very different from that example series.

Then my teacher said that we have to apply a model. In particular, he advised to apply Arima (or Holt Winter), in this way:

```
auto_arima(trend) #example output: (3,2,5)
train_data = trend.iloc[:600] #90% of samples
test_data = trend.iloc[600:] #10% of samples
model = ARIMA(train_data, order=(3,2,5)) #training
results = model.fit()
start = len(train_data)
end = len(train_data)+len(test)-1
predictions = results.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False, typ='levels')

model = ARIMA(trend, order=(3,2,5)) 
results = model.fit()
fcast = results.predict(len(trend), len(trend)+72, typ='levels') #prediction of 72 samples
```

But I wonder: can I use Arima for my specific series? Or should I use another model?
He also explained other concepts to us (stationarity, differentiation, autocorrelation, etc.), but all this was explained quickly and in a very short time and I have a lot of confusion in my head. Having never studied machine learning (I'll do it next semester), I can't easily understand the documentations on Internet.

Sorry for my ignorance on the subject, I'm a bit desperate.

Answer (score 0):

No worries, time series analysis is not very easy and hard, but I suggest you review your course materials at first. ARIMA model is the basic model to do the time series analysis. You should follow the instruction about how to decide its key arguments like p value, q value, or d value according to you series data.